# C/C++ pointer trick fix

Tags: c++, c, pointers, dereference

I'm trying this pointer trick and I can't figure out how to fix it, I'm running g++ 4.6 on ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. Check out this code below:

```
int arr[5];
arr[3] = 50;
((short*) arr)[6] = 2;
cout << arr[3] << endl;
```

The logic is: since `short` is 2 bytes, `int` is 4 bytes, I want to change the first 2 bytes in `arr[3]`, while keeping the value of the second 2 bytes as 50. So I'm just messing with the bit pattern. Unfortunately, `sizeof(int*)` and `sizeof(short*)` are both 8 bytes. Is there a type cast that returns a pointer of size 2 bytes?

**Update:**

I realized that the question is poorly written, so I'll fix that:
The output from `cout << arr[3] << endl;` I'm getting is 2. The output I would like to get is neither 2 nor 50, but rather a large number, indicating that the left part of the int bit pattern has been changed, while the right part (the second 2-bits) of the int stored in arr[3] is still unchanged.

Comment: You are manipulating bits of integers, not of pointers. Size of pointers is irrelevant. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Remember the `[]` operator is doing a deference.  `((short*) arr)[6]` is a `short` sized value.

Comment: I agree with you, but it's the only explanation I can think of for why it's not working :s

Comment: @naxchange: What "isn't working" about it? What is the behavior you are seeing, and what is the behavior you are expecting instead?

Comment: You're going to run into byte swapping and endianness issues if you try to manipulate data this way.

Comment: @Billy ONeal cout << arr[3] << endl;
What I'm seeing is 2. What I would like to see is some big number telling me that the value in the bit pattern stored in arr[3] has changed. Make sense?

Comment: @naxchange: Erm, the bit pattern did change. It used to be 50, and now it is 2.

Comment: @BillyONeal Please see the update above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizeof(int*)` and `sizeof(short*)` are both going to be the same -- as will `sizeof(void*)` -- you're asking for the size of a pointer, not the size of the thing the pointer points to.

Use `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(short)` instead.

---

Now, as for your code snippet, you are making assumptions about the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the machine on which you're running. The "first" part of the `int` on a given platform may be the bytes with higher address, or the bytes with lower address.

For instance, your memory block may be laid out like this. Let's say the least significant byte has index zero, and the most significant byte has index one. On a big endian architecture an int may look like this:

```
 <------------- 4 bytes --------------->
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| int:3   | int:2   | int:1   | int:0   |
| short:1 | short:0 | short:1 | short:0 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Notice how the first short in the int -- which in your case would have been `((short*) arr)[6]` -- contains the most significant bits of the int, not the least significant. So if you overwrite `((short*) arr)[6]`, you are overwriting the most significant bits of `arr[3]`, which appears to be what you wanted. But x64 is not a big endian machine.

On a little endian architecture, you would see this instead:

```
 <------------- 4 bytes --------------->
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| int:0   | int:1   | int:2   | int:3   |
| short:0 | short:1 | short:0 | short:1 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

leading to the opposite behavior -- `((short*) arr)[6]` would be the least significant bits of `arr[3]`, and `((short*) arr)[7]` would be the most significant.

---

Here's what my machine happens to do -- your machine may be different:

```
C:\Users\Billy\Desktop>type example.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        std::cout << "Size of int is " << sizeof(int) << " and size of short is "
                  << sizeof(short) << std::endl;

        int arr[5];
        arr[3] = 50;
        ((short*) arr)[6] = 2;
        std::cout << arr[3] << std::endl;
        ((short*) arr)[7] = 2;
        std::cout << arr[3] << std::endl;
}


C:\Users\Billy\Desktop>cl /W4 /EHsc /nologo example.cpp && example.exe
example.cpp
Size of int is 4 and size of short is 2
2
131074
```

Comment: The question doesn't imply a need for `sizeof(int)` or `...short...` - just a concern that the indexing wouldn't work as intended.

Comment: @TonyD: The question is a bit poorly written. The only question I see in this question (that is, ending with a `?`) is discussing `sizeof(int*)` and `sizeof(short*)`. Beyond that the OP hasn't been very clear about the behavior he is seeing versus the behavior he expects.

Comment: So, can I conclude that `((short*) arr)[7] = 2;` would resolve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Yes, yes it does. Thanks a million!

Comment: @naxchange: Yeah. Sorry, I off by one error'd all of the place there.

Comment: No problem, all's well that ends well. Thanks a lot, I didn't really know what endianness was, so that was a nice intro. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is due to [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  Intel CPU's are little endian meaning that the first byte of an int is stored in the the first address.  Let me how you can example:

Let's assume that arr[3] is at address 10:

Then `arr[3] = 50;` Writes the following to memory

```
10:   0x32
11:   0x00
12:   0x00
13:   0x00
```

And `((short*) arr)[6] = 2;` writes the following to memory

```
10:  0x02
11:  0x00
```

Comment: +1 -- but anyone who stores an `int` at a non-aligned address should be shot :)

Answer (score 0):

When you index a pointer, it adds the index multiplied by the size of the pointed-to type.  So, you don't need a 2-byte pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a lot of assumptions which might not hold water. Also what does the sizeof pointers have to do with the problem at hand?

Why not just use bit masks:

```
arr[3] |= (top_2_bytes << 16);
```

This should set the upper 16 bytes without disturbing the lower 16. (You may get into signed/unsigned dramas)

Answer (score 0):

Said all the above, the standard prohibits doing such things: Setting a variable through a pointer to another type is calling [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). *If* you know how your machine works (sizes of `int` and `short`, endianness, ...) *and*  you know how your compiler (is likely to) translate your code, *then* you might get away with it. Does for neat parlor tricks, and spectacular explosions when the machine/compiler/phase of the moon change.

If it wins any performance, the win will be minimal, and it could even be a net loss (one compiler long ago I fiddled with, playing the "I can implement this loop better than the compiler, I know exactly what goes on  here" generated *much* worse code for my `` `label:   ...  if() goto label; `` than the exact same written natively as a loop: My "smart" code confused the compiler, its "pattern for loops" did not apply).

Answer (score -1):

You wouldn't want your actual pointer to be of size two bytes; this would mean that it could only access ~16k of memory addresses. However, using a cast, as you are, to a short *, will let you access the memory every two bytes (since the compiler will view the array as an array of shorts, not of ints).